# Issue with streaming in realtime to HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg

ok so i created a project which should take an mkv file convert it to a sutaible fomrat in relatime and play it as it transcodes in the html 5 video player and should play as soon as small segement is ready for playback but unfornatlly it does seem to work heres my code if your curious, help would be very much appreicted

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Player</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="video-player" controls>
      <source src="output.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ffmpeg/0.11.6/ffmpeg.min.js" integrity="sha512-91IRkhfv1tLVYAdH5KTV+KntIZP/7VzQ9E/qbihXFSj0igeacWWB7bQrdiuaJVMXlCVREL4Z5r+3C4yagAlwEw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="player.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my javscript:

```
let mediaSource;
let sourceBuffer;
let isTranscoding = false;
let bufferedSeconds = 0;

async function setupMediaSource() {
  mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
  videoPlayer.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
      sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001E, mp4a.40.2"'); // Match the transcoded format
      sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
        if (!sourceBuffer.updating && mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
          mediaSource.endOfStream();
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

async function transcodeVideo() {
  const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
  const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');

  await ffmpeg.load();
  const transcodeCommand = ['-i', 'The Legend of Old Gregg S02E05.mkv', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'ultrafast', '-c:a', 'aac', '-strict', 'experimental', '-f', 'mp4', '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov', 'output.mp4'];

  const videoUrl = 'The Legend of Old Gregg S02E05.mkv'; // The URL of the original video file

  let lastBufferedSeconds = 0;
  let currentTime = 0;
  while (currentTime < videoPlayer.duration) {
    if (!isTranscoding && sourceBuffer.buffered.length > 0 && sourceBuffer.buffered.end(0) - currentTime < 5) {
      isTranscoding = true;
      const start = sourceBuffer.buffered.end(0);
      const end = Math.min(videoPlayer.duration, start + 10);
      await fetchAndTranscode(videoUrl, start, end, ffmpeg, transcodeCommand);
      isTranscoding = false;
      currentTime = end;
      bufferedSeconds += (end - start);
      const transcodingSpeed = bufferedSeconds / (currentTime);
      lastBufferedSeconds = bufferedSeconds;
      console.log(`Transcoded ${end - start} seconds of video. Buffered: ${bufferedSeconds.toFixed(2)}s (${transcodingSpeed.toFixed(2)}x speed)`);
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  }

  await ffmpeg.exit();
}

async function fetchAndTranscode(url, start, end, ffmpeg, transcodeCommand) {
  const response = await fetch(url, { headers: { Range: `bytes=${start}-${end}` } });
  const data = new Uint8Array(await response.arrayBuffer());
  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'input.mkv', data); // Use 'input.mkv' as a temporary file
  await ffmpeg.run(...transcodeCommand);
  const outputData = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.mp4');
  appendSegmentToBuffer(outputData);
}

function appendSegmentToBuffer(segment) {
  if (!sourceBuffer.updating) {
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(segment);
  } else {
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(segment);
    });
  }
}

async function createFFmpeg(options) {
  const { createFFmpeg } = FFmpeg;
  const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg(options);
  await ffmpeg.load();
  return ffmpeg;
}

(async () => {
  await setupMediaSource();
  await transcodeVideo();
})();
```